# Would error messages improve if we could disable features?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors

Inspired by [this reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/zemfe/ten_things_you_should_know_about_haskell_syntax/), I'm wondering if there are any technical obstacles in the way of a "Dr Scheme"-style approach to assisting beginners when it comes to comprehending error messages. A case in point is the notorious

```
Prelude> 1 "doesn't"

<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (Num ([Char] -> t0))
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num ([Char] -> t0))
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: 1 "doesn't"
    In an equation for `it': it = 1 "doesn't"
```

Suppose we were to make the local assumption that the programmer will declare *no new instances*. Indeed, one can get a long way in Haskell interacting with only prelude classes only via `deriving`, so this assumption is not unrealistic for beginners. Under such an assumption, the above error message would be beside the point. Could we improve upon it? We might still need to figure out how much to say about the type of `1`, but we could surely be more direct about the problem.

Are there other opportunities to reframe error messages on the basis of realistic simplifying assumptions? Note, I'm asking a question about changing the text of error messages based on a model of the programmer's experience: I am not locally considering any changes to which code is considered erroneous (e.g., by assuming that beginners will use overloaded things at specialised types, eliminating ambiguity).

A follow-up thought: does the text of the existing error messages contain enough information to support such transformations, assuming a "configuration file" modelling the student? That is, could an enterprising hacker implement an intelligibility-enhancing postprocessor for `ghci` without troubling the busy people at HQ?

Comment: I don't think it's just for beginners: I've been programming with type classes since Gofer turned up, and I find most of these `No instance for` error messages unhelpful. eg GHC, please tell me the types first: `"doesn't" :: String and 1 :: Num a => a` (pretty print this, but use in-scope type synonyms for readability - that's what they're for) `but in the epression: 1 "doesn't" you need: 1 :: String -> b` then suggest `add instance delaration for Num (String -> a)`. Telling me the inferred types helps me fix what was probably me forgetting what order some function takes its arguments.

Comment: Incidentally, on one occasion I received a "no instance" error because I had, in fact, written otherwise correct code that needed an instance I'd truly forgotten to write. I was tempted to make a note of the date, to preserve for posterity such a remarkable occurrence.

Comment: Update: The error message for `1 "doesn't"` is now (ghc 7.8.3) `No instance for (Num ([Char] -> a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’` `In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it.` I'm delighted that ghc has stopped suggesting adding instances. (The error message for 1 2 is fairly intimidating yet.)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not convinced that ignoring certain features for the sake of error messages would be helpful.

For one thing, are the errors encountered by beginners really *that* different from anyone else? Just because I know how to interpret a "no Num instance for this absurd thing which is clearly not a numeric type" error doesn't mean I wouldn't appreciate GHC more clearly pointing out what bone-headed thing I've done to provoke such a message.

I would suggest that the circumstances in which a beginner or an expert would be writing instances, or any other kind of "advanced" code, differ very little. The beginner, however, will be coding under those circumstances far less often, with an inclusive lower bound of "never".

If one wishes to insulate beginners from arcane corners of the language, then make sure they don't encounter them at all. For instance (ha, ha), there's an argument to be made for avoiding type classes entirely when first introducing the language.

I can't think of any cases where a more beginner-friendly error message, so long as it doesn't throw away information, would not also be more pleasant for everyone else as well.

> Suppose we were to make the local assumption that the programmer will declare *no new instances.*

Suppose we instead make the assumption that the programmer will declare no *orphan* instances where the class and/or type are defined by the Haskell Report. This assumption is most assuredly realistic for beginners and, in fact, seems reasonable as a general rule.

Adding such an instance because of a compiler error at all is plausible in very few situations. With the glaring and galling exception of the anonymous writer monad (unless that has been remedied since I last checked) orphan instances for a standard class *and* type seems exceedingly unlikely, and one or the other should only arise when a library has unexpectedly overlooked a few instances, or is old and dusty enough to predate the prevalence of stuff like `Applicative` or `Foldable`. In any case, anyone who *does* want such an instance can be safely assumed to know what they're doing well enough to interpret GHC's error message, whatever it may be.

But enough about that particular example.

> Are there other opportunities to reframe error messages on the basis of realistic simplifying assumptions?

Very likely, but we're also very far from exhausting the space of realistic complicating assumptions!

The point of the above digression on instances is that by using information already available to the compiler and heuristics that examine a larger context (e.g., where certain things are defined, to distinguish the above example from non-orphan instances) error messages could be improved in general.

> A follow-up thought: does the text of the existing error messages contain enough information to support such transformations, assuming a "configuration file" modelling the student?

I really can't see this working very well except in the simplest and most egregious cases, the example you gave being a notable example. It could rephrase existing flavors of error, but beginners would benefit most from having more detailed/explicit information that the existing message may not contain.

Consider two other error messages that are chronically vexing to beginners: complaints about matching "rigid type variables", and complaints about "infinite types". Rephrasing might improve those somewhat, but short of including a tutorial on polymorphism in each error message it's not going to much help a beginner fix their code, unless you can interpret the relevant expression and type well enough to be specific about the cause.

Together with inspecting the source code a "translator" might have some legs, but I suspect modifying GHC directly will quickly become the easiest route. Generating error messages would be an interesting extensibility point, but I don't think this can be done with GHC's existing plugin infrastructure.

---

The greatest obstacle to any of this, I expect, is not implementation. Rather, it's the decision of which heuristics would improve error messages rather than accomplishing the opposite. Without a base of objective data, this is something of an error-prone (ha, ha) guessing game. It would be very interesting to assemble a large survey of errors encountered by (primarily intermediate or novice) Haskell programmers and, most importantly, what actual *change* they made to resolve the issue.

Comment: Interesting points: thanks for taking the trouble to think about it. I'm given to believe that the Helium people have a large corpus of beginner errors. I think there is room to consider modelling "what the programmer is probably trying to do" when constructing an error message. Such models might be informed by things like specimen solutions, as well as by an estimate of student experience.

Comment: @pigworker: Interesting; I've never used Helium and wasn't aware they might have such a thing. Stack Overflow itself is a not-inconsiderable source of data as well--amusingly, the "Related" links it chooses for this question already provide an excellent overview of such stumbling blocks. Perhaps examining such data would indicate places where filtering things for beginners would make sense, but I'm skeptical of the benefit until then.

Comment: To your list of incomprehensible error messages, let me add any mention of skolem variables. These aren't even part of the language so much as part of the type checker implementation.

Comment: @dfeuer: They sure like trying to escape though! It almost seems cruel to keep them caged up. :[ :[

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the  [Helium](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/Helium) subset of Haskell is an attempt to do this. It has been a long time since I have tried it but IIRC, it produced much better error messages than GHC.

Comment: Are there programs which compile because of simplifying assumptions made by Helium which would not compile in the full horror of GHC? Any attempts to do better than GHC are very welcome, but I think it's also worth thinking about cheap ways to make GHC do better.